# Dynamically validate user selection using ajax/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

See below my simple html form. I want a user to pick a product from the dropdown list.After this, proceed to pick quantity from the  next dropdown list and add to cart.

Here is the question: at the point of selecting the quantity, I want the system to dynamically go to the Database(PHP/MYSQL), compare the database qty with the selected value. If it is greater than the stock value(total value in DB), then it should pop up a message like alert box and disable the submit buttom, otherwise it should add to cart and enable the submit button.

I have looked at many ajax examples and help, but hasn't been able to get it. Will appreciate a sample/modification if necessary.

```
<p>Product Name:<select name="prod_name" size="1">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<?php
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['prod_name'];?>"><?php echo $line['prod_name'];?> </option>  
<?php } ?> 

</select></p>
<p>Quantity:<input  type="number" name="qty"  size="30"  required="required"/></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" /> | <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you would do well to use jQuery. The first thing to do is to fire off some code when the quantity changes

```
<script>
$( "input[name='qty']" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called you selected Quantity " + this.value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you assist with the sample of the code that will be fired when quantity changes.

Comment: By the way, you may want to rethink your strategy here. I assume your goal is to prevent people from adding quantities of an item to their basket that are not available in stock. Problem being that by the time they check out, the stock may well have changed, and your users purchase will have to be amended in any case.
It would probably be easier to check the stock value before drawing the page, limit the drop-down to that number so that the user cannot select  a greater number than that in stock in the first place. Far easier.But still: stock levels could change by check-out time.

Comment: @ Foxbeefly: good strategy. thanks. However, pls give me a sample code of limiting the dropdown box to the max quantity in the stock using php/mysqli.

Comment: Query your database to get stock available for the item, then output your quantity dropdown, adding a loop to create the dropdown options, limited by the value retrieved by your query.

Very roughly:

`$stock_level  = get_stock_on_hand_function($productID);

echo '<select name="prod_name">':
for ($i = 1; $i <= $stock_level; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">"'.$i.'"</option>';
}
echo '</select>';`

Comment: take a look at my code: it is doesn't work but when i hardcode it works. where lies the error:

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the `value` that you want to send via `ajax`. Then, you do your server side action as comparing the with the selected value.
I do this code to show you what you should do! :)

```
$("#select").change(function() {
    var valueOpt = $("option:selected", this).attr("value");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "YourURL",
        data: {yourParams: valueOpt},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Get the value via the `change event`, then pass it into `yourParams`, by the way, you can retrieve this value with php: echo `$_POST['yourParams']`. Do your request, and compare now the value! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below happen when you are changing the value in your quantity and it will run an ajax call to check if the quantity is greater than your stock.

```
<p>Product Name:<select name="prod_name" id="prod_name" size="1">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<?php
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['prod_name'];?>">
<?php echo $line['prod_name'];?> </option>  
<?php } ?> 

</select></p>
<p>Quantity:<input  type="number" id="qty" name="qty"  
size="30"  required="required"/></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btn" value="Add to Cart" /> | 
<input name="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" />

<script>
$('#qty').change(function(){
var prodname = $(#prod_name).val();
var qty= $(#qty).val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_php_',
    data:{prodname: prodname, qty: qty},
    success: function(e){
        if(e == 'true'){
            /*if the quantity is greater than the stock*/
            alert('Your MEssage');
            $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: Pls i am new to aajx, so I need more explanation/assistance. The line(2) is showing error. ie var. Also, the url which is the php script that will fetch total stock from database. How will I be able to determine the product. e.g    $val = "SELECT qty FROM stock WHERE prod_name='".GET['prod_name']."'; $conf = mysqli_query($con,$val); $fetchVal = mysqli_fetch_array($conf); $stock = $fetchVal['prod_name']; pls, check am I on course or how can i get this

Comment: checkout the prodname that is where you get the name of the product. you shoud $_GET that into your php where your query is

Comment: Pls i am new to ajax, so I need more explanation/assistance. The line(2) is showing error. ie var. Also, the url which is the php script that will fetch total stock from database. How will I be able to determine the product. e.g    $val = "SELECT qty FROM stock WHERE prod_name='".GET['prod_name']."'; $conf = mysqli_query($con,$val); $fetchVal = mysqli_fetch_array($conf); $stock = $fetchVal['prod_name']; pls, check am I on course or how is there a way to do it better. Also, note that this will mean I have to make the user click, but I don't think that is a good idea. pls help.

Comment: I edited the code above to include a quantity to pass it to the php where the query is. now we have pass the product name and the quantity in the form. what you have to do is to get that product name and quantity to your php. your query should check if the selected product stock is less than quantity, you can echo 'true' or else 'false' and in success of the ajax the result in your php will check if its true or false.

Comment: pls pardon my question, just that I tried it and still not getting it. here is the URL:  url: 'confirmStock.php', and this is the content:<?php 
if(isset($_POST['prod_name'])){
 
  $getVal = $_GET['prod_name']; 
 //stockValue($getVal);
 // function stockValue($getVal){ 
 global $connection;
  $val = "SELECT units FROM pharmacy_stock_tab WHERE prod_name='".$getVal."'";
   $conf = mysqli_query($connection,$val); 
   $fetchVal = mysqli_fetch_array($conf);
   $stock = $fetchVal['units']; 
   return $stock;
   //echo  $stock;
// }
}
 ?> Pls where am I missing it.

Comment: change $_POST['prod_name'] to $_GET['prod_name']

Comment: @ Kenken, I have tried it but it is not working. What else do U suggest I do or is there another means of dynamically validating a user selection without refreshing the page?

Comment: this would work. lets do this 1 by 1 first create a php script that has a static value of the product id and quantity. now query get your product stock. like this `"$sql = SELECT stock FROM productTable where id = $product_id AND stock <= $quantity"; $query = mysqli_query($sql); $count = mysqli_num_rows($query); if($count == 0){ echo 'false' }else{ echo 'true'; }`

Comment: Kenken: this is what I did again, just to hardcode it to see, yet not working:<?php require_once("/includes/db_connection.php");?> 
<?php require_once("/includes/functions.php");?> 
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['prod_name'])){
 
  $getProd = $_GET['prod_name']; 
  $getQty = $_GET['units'];
  $product_id=16;
  $quantity =4;
 global $connection;
$sql = "SELECT units FROM pharmacy_stock_tab where sn = '$product_id' AND units <='$quantity'";
 $query = mysqli_query($sql); 
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
 if($count == 0){ echo 'false'; }else{ echo 'true'; }

Comment: do not use isset for now because you will not going to pass a value. let me know if you can echo true or false base on the result in your query

Comment: on running the confirmStock.php alone, it returns true. what next?

Comment: ok. see the above javascript that I answered. `$('#qty').change(function(){` that part means that you will trigger the function inside that (which is ajax) when your quantity in the form have changed. now that ajax has a `data:{prodname: prodname, qty: qty}` the prodname is the data that you selected in your product dropdown. the qty ofcourse that quantity. in the `success` part you notice that I have the if else function. there you can use the echo in your php.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$('select').on('change', function () { // Better if you put class in your html tags when your using it in either CSS or JS
    $.ajax({
        url: urlToGetTheResultOfMySQL, // this page must have the query to your database that will receive the data in the AJAX POST
        type: 'POST',
        data {
            qty: this.value // you can get this qty value via $_POST['qty']
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 1) { 
            /* if you prefer that your logic will only return 1 if the 
               quantity exceeds the in one your database, disabled the  
               submit button, but it's much better to remove the input tag  
               and replace it with just a dummy button */
                $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, just ask me if there are vague explanations in my code, haven't tested it yet so feel free to ask.

Comment: Pls how will the query to the DB looks like, and how to send it? Will something like this work?$val = "SELECT qty FROM stock WHERE prod_name='".$_GET['prod_name']."'";
   $conf = mysqli_query($con,$val); 
   $fetchVal = mysqli_fetch_array($conf);
    $stock = $fetchVal['prod_name'];